# Why is the variable not in scope?

Tags: haskell, floating-point

I have similar code working but using getWord8 and getWord32le so why is getFloatle giving me error?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary.Get

readfloat :: BS.ByteString -> Int -> Float
readfloat contents startpos = runGet getFloatle (BS.drop (fromIntegral startpos) contents)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myfile = "DATA.BIN"
    contents <- BS.readFile myfile
    let stuff = readfloat contents 1042346125
    print stuff
```

Getting the following error:

```
test2.hs:7:38: error:
    Variable not in scope: getFloatle :: Get Float
```

Comment: Can you show your similar code ?

Comment: Which version of the binary package do you have? `getFloatle` and friends is in [the latest](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.4.1/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html), but not in the randomly picked [0.8.1.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.1.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html).

Comment: I installed using https://haskell.org/platform/download/8.0.1/haskell-platform-8.0.1-unknown-posix--full-x86_64.tar.gz which is supposed to be the latest. Cabal is showing 0.8.3.0 for the binary package.

Comment: can you pls provide the content of DATA.BIN file, or a sample of it.

Comment: @Vlam: Well yes, that might be the latest version of the *Haskell platform*. The Haskell platform consists of a set of "core" packages at versions known to work well with eachother. The platform version you installed probably ships with a version of binary from before `getFloatle` was introduced.

Comment: @iuriisusuk: The content of DATA.BIN can't possibly be relevant to this compilation error.

Comment: @gspr the first step to find a problem is to reproduce it)

Comment: @iuriisusuk: OP has a compiler error. To the compiler, DATA.BIN exists only as a string in the program. There is obviously no problem with that string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getFloatle` was added in binary-0.8.4.0. I guess you are using binary-0.8.3.0, maybe from Stackage or the Haskell platform.

To use the newest binary version, the first step is to put a lower bound in the cabal file. For example:

...

```
  build-depends:
    ...,
    binary >= 0.8.4.0 && < 0.9,
    ...
...
```

This says that you want at least version 0.8.4.0 (so you can use `getFloatle`) and at most version 0.8.something (so you're protected against future breaking changes that might be introduced by the 0.9 series). You can also leave out the `&& < 0.9` if you don't care about the protection against future changes.

If you're compiling your code with cabal with this updated cabal file, `cabal` should download and install an appropriate version of `binary` for you.

Comment: I have just installed the 0.8.4.1 version of the binary package using cabal and all seems to be working fine. Will add the build-depends when I create the cabal file for my package after my development and testing are done. Right now compiling with ghc so I don't think that supports the build-depends functionality.